# Laravel how to stub view rendering

Tags: php, controller, laravel-4, tdd

I'm trying to do controller testing with laravel 4.1 without touching the database. So im using the repository pattern and I mock the repositories and make them return dummy model objetcs/dummy model collections.

The problem is, the view is trying to use the models relationships etc... And it fails because relationships can't work as the database is empty.

Is there a way to bypass the view rendering as rails do ?

Comment: what do you mean by 'view is trying to use the models relationships' ?  View should never know about the internal details of data passed to it.

Comment: If a post has many comments, the view may iterate through $post->comments. It fires a query to retreive the comments. As my database isn't seeded (and I dont want to seed it just for this purpose) it may cause problems.

Comment: You should take a look into eager loading eloquent models here http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#eager-loading and prefetch the data in repositories before passing it onto the view, then pass the Collection of data to the view, not the model itself.

Answer (score 0):

Read about [testing environment](http://laravel.com/docs/configuration#environment-configuration) and [mocking](http://laravel.com/docs/testing#mocking-facades) in Laravel

Comment: Of course I know testing environment and it isn't related to my question. I'm trying to mock the view facade but I cant get it to work, thats why im asking.

Comment: It is related because you said that you won't touch the database. Anyway, improve the question to get more accurate answers.